# How to prevent a document-based cocoa application to open ANY document?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

Recently, a document that was saved caused a crash whenever I would start my app. Is there a way to prevent a doc-based app from opening *any* document, including a new empty or the last active document(s)? I'd like to do that not by using OSX functionality (outside the scope of my app), but within my program.

I would think that this should be done through the `NSDocumentController` somehow, but I cannot figure it out and have had no luck finding answers elsewhere.

So, how to tell an OSX app (through `NSDocumentController`) to not open any documents at startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for functionality that is defined in the NSApplicationDelegate-protocol. Specifically the following two methods give you some control over what happens on app start:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
```

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more.